# EF Core 6 automatically add navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, ef-core-6.0

Imagine I had the following code.

```
var myEntity = Context.MyEntities.GetById(id);
myEntity.SomeNavigationProperty = new MyNavigationProperty(...);
await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I have the following mapping for MyEntity

```
builder.HasOne(o => o.SomeNavigationProperty).WithOne().HasForeignKey<MyEntity>(o => o.SomeNavigationPropertyId);
```

SaveChangesAsync fail with:

> The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

If I look at the change tracker after save, `MyNavigationProperty` has been marked as modified and not added.

Versions that work

```
var myEntity = new MyEntity(...);
myEntity.SomeNavigationProperty = new MyNavigationProperty(...);
await Context.AddAsync(myEntity);
await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

and

```
var myEntity = Context.MyEntities.GetById(id);
myEntity.SomeNavigationProperty = new MyNavigationProperty(...);
await Context.AddAsync(myEntity.SomeNavigationProperty);
await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This behavior makes sense to a degree if I read up on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addasync?view=efcore-6.0. I do not completely understand why ef core decides to mark the untracked entity as modified instead of added though.

Either way... my problem is that my domain and repository are separated. In other words when the property gets set I do not have access to the context.

Is there a way I can tell the EF Core context to re-add all if its not already added without it complaining about duplicates?

Something like

```
await Context.RefreshAddAsync(myEntity);
```

where `RefreshAddAsync` will skip `MyEntity` (if it's already added) and mark `MyNavigationProperty` as added.

Any other suggestions appreciated. Worse case scenario I'll write a version of `RefreshAddAsync` using reflection, but would like a cleaner solution if there is one.

Comment: Do you have a constraint on not having a back navigation property ?

Comment: Have you provided an explicit PK value as part of `new MyNavigationProperty(...)`? Have you defined the foreign key the wrong way around? If you are generating keys on the client, you may need to explicitly `Context.NavDbSet.Add(myEntity.SomeNavigationProperty)`.

Comment: @ArwynFr yes unfortunately.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I am pretty sure the mapping is correct. As stated, I don't have access to the context when setting it. Hence the best I can do would be the last sentence of the answer.

Comment: Does `GetById` support eager loading (some way to specify the equivalent of EF Core `Include`)?

Comment: Yes it loads the entire aggregate root.

Comment: Do you really need to `AddAsync()` ? " This method is async only to allow special value generators, such as the one used by 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo', to access the database asynchronously. For all other cases the non async method should be used. " ; have you tried `Add()` instead ?

Comment: @ArwynFr if you reed the ones that work. AddAsync solves the issue, but I don't want to explicitly call Add on the navigation property.

Comment: Can you share definition of MyEntity ?

Comment: You can image that it only has an Id, SomeNavigationProperty, and SomeNavigationPropertyId

Comment: Could you share the GetById code?

Comment: Its literally just Context.MyEntities.Include(x=>x.SomeNavigationProperty ).SingleAsync(o.Id == id)

Comment: Can't reproduce with the provided information. The problem scenario in question works as expected in latest EFC 6.0.6 - on `SaveChanges`, the referenced entity is created and then the referencing entity FK is updated.  No exceptions. There must be some specific detail (property or configuration) in the entity model missing in the question. Please provide [mre].

Comment: I'll try and add an mre over the weekend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this which works pretty well.

```
public static async Task AddOrUpdateEntityAsync<T>(this ArtBankContext context, T entity)
        where T : DomainEntity
{
    context.ThrowIfNull();
    entity.ThrowIfNull();

    var toProcessQueue = new Queue<DomainEntity>();
    var processed = new List<DomainEntity>();

    var tracked = RunWithAutoDetectChangesDisabled(() => context.ChangeTracker
        .Entries<DomainEntity>()
        .Select(o => o.Entity));

    toProcessQueue.Enqueue(entity);

    while (toProcessQueue.Any())
    {
        var toProcess = toProcessQueue.Dequeue();

        if (!tracked.Any(o => o == toProcess))
        {
            await context
                .AddEntityAsync(toProcess)
                    .ContinueOnAnyContext();
        }

        foreach (var toProcessPropertyInfo in toProcess
            .GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(o => o.PropertyType.IsAssignableTo(typeof(DomainEntity))))
        {
            var toProcessProperty = (DomainEntity?)toProcessPropertyInfo.GetValue(toProcess);

            if (toProcessProperty == null || processed.Any(o => o == toProcessProperty))
                continue;

            toProcessQueue.Enqueue(toProcessProperty);
        }

        processed.Add(toProcess);
    }

    TResult RunWithAutoDetectChangesDisabled<TResult>(Func<TResult> func)
    {
        //Ef auto detects changes when you call methods like context.ChangeTracker.Entries
        //In this specific use case the entities that we want to add dynamically gets detected and incorreectly added to the contexts.
        //Hence we disable the flag before executing
        var originalAutoDetectChangesEnabledValue = context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled;

        context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

        var result = func();

        context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = originalAutoDetectChangesEnabledValue;

        return result;
    }
}
```

it is the used like

```
var myEntity = Context.MyEntities.GetById(id);
myEntity.SomeNavigationProperty = new MyNavigationProperty(...);
await Context.AddOrUpdateEntityAsync(myEntity);
await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken MyEntities is item and SomeNavigationProperty is parent. You have an item and you work to create a parent for your current item. Your this code seems like the most appropriate method for this situation:

```
var myEntity = Context.MyEntities.GetById(id);
myEntity.SomeNavigationProperty = new MyNavigationProperty(...);
await Context.AddAsync(myEntity.SomeNavigationProperty);
await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

But if you have parent data. You can do like this:

```
var someNavigationProperty = Context.SomeNavigationProperty.GetById(id);
someNavigationProperty.MyEntities = anyMyEntitiesData;
await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to your constraints I would try the following:

The default constructor of your navigation property sets its Id property to some special value, defined as ´public static readonly` field on the entity (e.g. -1 or Guid.NewGuid()).

At next add an [interceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors#the-interceptor) to your context that's being executed before `SaveChanges()` and within that method ask the ChangeTracker to give you all entities, filtered by the navigation property type, the special Id value and the state being Modified. Now change on all these items the entity state to be Added and exit your interceptor.

Unfortunately I can't create a working example right now, but IMHO this should solve your problem. I also ran into this problem when upgrading to EF core 6, but on all places I had access to the context class itself and could add the navigation property to the corresponding context collection directly to avoid this problem, but I think the above described way should also work.